# how to set the currently taken image in the listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-camera-intent

i have doing the listview in that i have set the currently taken images in the listview,but my problem is i am displaying the image for the current Item to be added in the list view but my images is viewing for the whole item which have already is created please help me thank you.

Comment: It will be help full if you can explain your problem with the help of code which you have tried.

Comment: this is my adapter class where i insert the image(i am unable insert the code fully sorry)    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertview;
        try {ViewHolder holder;
  if (vi == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_trip_list_view_items, null);    holder.place_images = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_Image_view);

                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show current taken image top of list. then please use System.currentTimeMillis(); and sort your list according to your current time.

it will help.